# Social Login plugin question

Tags: php, configuration, plugin-social-login

I am using the Social Login plugin from Dukt. It mentions in the configuration instructions to add things to a social.php file that you place in craft>config.

I've done that, but I assume I'm doing something wrong with the PHP file, as it just shows up in the CP on the social login settings page, rather than actually performing the additional functions I'm looking for.

I'm not super well-versed in PHP, so I'm sure its user error. Can anyone help? Here's the contents of my PHP file:

```
'lockDomains' => [
'awebaddress.net']
```

And here is what is showing up in the control panel: 
[image: control panel screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Your `/craft/config/social.php` file should probably look like this:

```
<?php

return [
    'lockDomains' => [
        'awebaddress.net',
    ],
];
```

If you wanted to add more config settings, that would look like this:

```
<?php

return [
    'lockDomains' => [
        'awebaddress.net',
    ],
    'allowEmailMatch' => false,
];
```